# Query all items in table that does not have a relation to other item in other table in ORMLITE

Tags: ormlite, query-builder

I have two tables StockItem and StockItemGroup. There is many to many relation between those tables made by StockItemGroupStockItem table. I need to make query that queries for all StockItems that does not have relation to any StockItemGroup. I have tried this code, but it does not work:

```
QueryBuilder<StockItemEntity, Long> qbSI = stockItemDao.queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<StockItemGroupStockItemEntity, Long> qbSIG_SI = stockItemGroupStockItemDao.queryBuilder();

List<StockItemEntity> stockItemEntitiesWithoutGroup = null;
qbSI.where().not().exists(qbSIG_SI);
stockItemEntitiesWithoutGroup = qbSI.query();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I was missing code that maps relation between two tables:

```
qbSIG_SI.where().eq(StockItemGroupStockItemEntity.STOCK_ITEM_ID, new ColumnArg(StockItemEntity.TABLE_NAME, StockItemEntity.ID_FIELD_NAME));
```